# looping on parent controls in order

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, controls

im looping on 24 picturebox on groupbox for displaying something, but it doesn't loop in the right order, it may start at the 18th picture box and here is the code im using

```
foreach (var pb in groupBox1.Controls)
{
    if (pb is PictureBox && previewIndexer < Previewer.Count)
    {
        try
        {
            ((PictureBox)pb).Image = ...
            previewIndexer++;
            ...
        }
        catch
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

i would want to loop in ascending order of which it loops on picturebox1 first till picturebox24, thanks and have wonderful day

Comment: how do you know it's `18th picturebox`? by its name?

Comment: How can you say ascending? I mean how are you maintainning indexing?

Comment: @kingking by it's name and position, the pictures are there with there original naming order, that's why i expect it to loop in order so it display them in order too

Comment: @muctadir the pictures are named in order which picturebox1 is the first and picturebox24 is the last, where the indexer isn't really related here it's for casting pictures in the picturebox for some other purpose , and what you gentlemen said until now wasn't related to the problem im having , all i want is to loop in order of creation or naming as both is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is ordering controls by name. You need alphanumeric sorting in order to `picturebox10` go after `picturebox5`. This can be done if you will sort pictureboxes by numbers in their names:

```
foreach (var pb in groupBox1.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()
               .OrderBy(x => Int32.Parse(x.Name.Substring("picturebox".Length))))
{
    pb.Image = ...;
}
```

I would even created some method like (it removes all non-numeric characters from control name and tries to parse rest to integer value):

```
private int GetControlId(Control control)
{
   int id;
   string idToParse = Regex.Replace(control.Name, @"\D+", "");
   return Int32.TryParse(idToParse, out id) ? id : 0;
}
```

And used this method in query

```
var pictureBoxes = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>();

foreach (var pb in pictureBoxes.OrderBy(GetControlId))
{
    pb.Image = ...;
}
```

Comment: ^ and that's ladies and gentlemen is one pro programmer XD that was really smart, linq is awesome so you are XD thanks, will accept it once possible

Answer (score 0):

You can take benefit of `LINQ` here, suppose you named your pictureboxes as `picture1`, `picture2`, ...

```
foreach (var pb in groupBox1.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().OrderBy(p=>int.Parse(Regex.Replace(k,"\\D*",""))))
{
     if(previewIndexer < Previewer.Count) {
                try
                {
                    ((PictureBox)pb).Image = ...
                    previewIndexer++;
                    ...
                }
                catch
                {
                    ...
                }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can index the Controls property with a string which refers to the name of the control.
This might be the simpliest solution:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 24; i++)
{
     PictureBox pb = groupBox1.Controls["picturebox" + i.ToString()] as PictureBox;
}
```

Comment: True...but instead of `Controls`, you'd use `groupBox1.Controls`.  If the PictureBoxes were spread across several containers you could use `this.Controls.Find()`.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Ok, I modified the example source according to the groupBox, although it doesn't change anything important. The Find() method looks interesting though, but as I understand the OP's controls are all located in one groupBox container.